# Adding a calculated column using different table SQL

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

I'm new to SQL so please bear with me.

I am trying to add a calculated column `InvoiceAmount` to my `CompanyInvoice` table.

My table currently has the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE CompanyInvoice
(
    InvoiceID        CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    CompanyAccountID CHAR(5) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_CompanyInvoice_CompanyAccount    
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CompanyAccount(CompanyAccountID) 
                    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CompanyID        CHAR(5) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_CompanyInvoice_ProductionCompany 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProductionCompany(CompanyID), 
    BookingID        CHAR(5) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_CompanyInvoice_EventBooking      
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EventBooking (BookingID),
    TheatreID        CHAR(5) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_CompanyInvoice_Theatre           
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Theatre(TheatreID)
                    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I would like to add a new column which calculates the invoice amount - invoice amount is calculated dependent on duration of event (`EventDuration` column is held in an `Event` table) and the `TheatreID`, for example if `TheatreID=1` then `EventDuration x 300`, if `TheatreID=2` then `EventDuration x 1000`.

Many thanks

Comment: Despite this is not a good idea , you need a trigger on event table

Comment: I think a *view* would be more applicable here.

Comment: How would you conduct this in a view? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view, as you described, would look like

```
create view v_invoice as
select c.InvoiceID,
       e.EventDuration * case when c.TheatreID = 1 then 300
                              when c.TheatreID = 2 then 1000
                         end as invoice_amount
from CompanyInvoice c join ... ??? unknown; how to get to Event table?
```

As you can see, `???` means that you didn't describe how to get from data we know to `Event` table.

---

On the other hand, it is probably not a very good idea to multiply anything with hardcoded values (`300`, `1000`) because - what if they change? Will you modify all code you write to implement those changes? From what you said so far, those should be another column in `Theatre` table (or a new table, if you want to track changes over time; that new table would be in parent-child relationship with `Theatre`).

Something like this (note that I'm still guessing join conditions):

```
create view v_invoice as
select c.InvoiceID,
       e.EventDuration * t.value as invoice_amount
                         -------
                         this, instead of hardcoded 300 or 1000 or ...
from CompanyInvoice c join Theatre t on t.TheatreID = c.TheatreID
                      join Event e on e.EventID = t.EventID
```